# Why does the strptime function not interpret the date_time_str2 case here?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I've reviewed this many times and don't understand why the str2 case won't convert correct? This is being run in Python 3.8.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

print(time.tzname)

date_time_str1 = '(2021,10,4)   (19,36,21)'
date_time_str2 = 'Mon Oct 4 11:13:08 2021'

print(date_time_str1)
print(date_time_str2)

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str1, '(%Y,%m,%d) (%H,%M,%S)')
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str2, '%A %B %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'` because your day and month names are abbreviated.